# How can I stop this looping statement

Tags: java, loops

I want a code that keeps telling you to enter two numbers until you enter two numbers that are even multiples. I am using a loop statement for this task and when I run my code and I type two numbers that are not even multiples it keeps saying "Please enter even multiples". Please help me. Thx in advance. Here is my code.

```
public class looper {
      public static void main (String[] args) {

     float firstNumber = 0;
     float secondNumber = 0;   
     float finalNumber = 0;

     java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Enter your first number."); 
        firstNumber = input.nextFloat();
        input.nextLine();


        System.out.println("Enter your second number."); 
        secondNumber = input.nextFloat();

         finalNumber = firstNumber % secondNumber;

         System.out.println(secondNumber + " and " + firstNumber + " are even multiples.");
     while(finalNumber != 0) { 

        System.out.println("Please enter even multiples.");


        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to your end goal.  I can see how to fix the loop, but what do you actually want to happen with `finalNumber` - do you want it to keep calculating in the same manner as you did outside of the loop?

Comment: if the final number is not zero, I want the code to ask the user to re enter his numbers. If the final number is 0, then i want the program to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set the value of `finalNumber` in such a way that it will satisfy the terminating condition for your `while` loop.  You probably wanted to do something like this (I haven't compiled this code!):

```
while (finalNumber != 0){

    System.out.println("Enter your first number."); 
    firstNumber = input.nextFloat();
    input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your second number."); 
    secondNumber = input.nextFloat();

    finalNumber = firstNumber % secondNumber;

}
System.out.println(secondNumber + " and " + firstNumber + " are even multiples.");
```

Comment: It terminates when `finalNumber == 0`.  What you probably meant was that one had to ensure that `finalNumber` actually made it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Be careful where you calculate the condition for your `while` loop.**  If you do not update the variable you use to check inside of your loop, you will enter into an infinite loop.

The important thing here is that you require two values from the user.  You don't *really* need a third variable to keep track of it depending on how you write it, but it could be authored in this way:

- Get value #1
- Get value #2
- While `value1 % value2 == 0`...

  - ...print message and retrieve value #1 and value #2 from the user again.
- Print the completion message.

```
System.out.println("Enter your first number."); 
firstNumber = input.nextFloat();
input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter your second number."); 
secondNumber = input.nextFloat();

while(firstNumber % secondNumber != 0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter two numbers that are multiples of each other.");
    System.out.println("Enter your first number."); 
    firstNumber = input.nextFloat();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your second number."); 
    secondNumber = input.nextFloat();
}

// afterwards, print whatever message you require.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem in not using while then use if condition. Make two separate functions. One is to check the condition which calls the other condition to get the result. Here is a sample code. Hope that, it will help you. Sorry for may bad English.

```
public class Looper 
{
      public static void main (String[] args) 
      {
          Looper looper = new Looper();
          looper.runTest();
      }

      public void runTest()
      {
          float finalNumber = getResult();
          System.out.println("finalNumber: " + finalNumber);
          if(finalNumber != 0.0) 
         { 
            System.out.println("Please enter even multiples.");
            runTest();
         }
      }

      public float getResult()
      { 
          java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Enter your first number."); 
          float firstNumber = input.nextFloat();
          input.nextLine();

          System.out.println("Enter your second number."); 
          float secondNumber = input.nextFloat();
          float finalNumber = firstNumber % secondNumber;
          System.out.println(secondNumber + " and " + firstNumber + " are even multiples.");
          return finalNumber;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use an if statement because you just want to inform the user that numbers entered are not correct

```
do{
    System.out.println("Enter your first number."); 
    firstNumber = input.nextFloat();
    input.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Enter your second number."); 
    secondNumber = input.nextFloat();

    finalNumber = firstNumber % secondNumber;
    if(finalNumber!=0)
        System.out.println("values not correct ");
}while(finalNumber!=0);
```

Comment: A loop is desired, and I don't see how this would fix the issue.

Comment: i need a loop because i do not want the program to stop running. basically if the final number is not zero, I want the code to ask the user to re enter his numbers. If the final number is 0, then i want the program to finish.

Comment: accept the answer, if it worked, click on the tick to left of answer

Comment: You **do not** need an `if` statement there.

Comment: thats just for giving reason to user,that why are we expecting more inputs from him, it has nothing to do with logic